# QT Model/View programming: how should I retrieve extra data for context menu options?

Tags: python, qt, view, model, pyside

I've just started programming QT and need to put together a small utility that displays data in a treeview and allows associated data to be edited in text fields. The hierarchy to be displayed in the treeview consists of different object types and I need to enable/disable different options in the menus based on type of object selected. The information for enabling/disabling the menu options should not be part of the displayed information in the treeview so I discounted using a field in data()

Is there a way to extend QAbstractItemModel so I can neatly retrieve the information I need? Or have I completely misunderstood the concept and need to somehow access the selected object directly when displaying the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's far more than display content in QXXXModel's data(). Refer to QStandardItemModel::data() or setData() there's a parameter called Qt::Role role, which specifies what the data is used for. data() actually refers to a QMap, by default we get QVariant corresponding to Qt::DisplayRole, and other roles such as Qt::Decoration data stores the icon, from Qt::CustomRole+1, custom data can be stored and retrieved. For example:

```
SetupDataModel{
    const int MyInfoRole = Qt::CustomRole + 100; 
    QAbstractItemModel *model = view->model();
    model->setData(index, "Display text"); // for display
    QVariant objectType(....); // your "hidden" information to be stored, say an integer indicating type, or a string
    model->setData(index, objectType, MyInfoRole);

}

On_item_clicked{
    // when the item is selected
    QVariant objType = index.data(); 
    // cast the objType to your information
}
```

Comment: that was exactly what the tip I needed, thanks! I had trouble picking up on this when using the SDK and online Documentation. I have a feeling that I'm probably missing out on other important things too. Can you suggest a reference that explains the all the important mechanisms of the Qt MVC? (either online or in dead-tree format)

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html  or http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html#details as a class entrance